# connect to xampp mysql from another ip Address

Tags: mysql, xampp, database-connection

I have created a xampp Server in my office which can be used from the office via any pc when they are connected to the same network.
but when I connect using my personal internet it doesn't connect to the xampp server.
Is there any setting to make the server globally connect by anyone even they are not in same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must setup and public virtual servers on your modem/ router

For example on my TL-WR841N:

go to: menu->Forwarding -> Virtual Servers

**Virtual Servers**

Service Port: 80

Internal Port:80

IP Address  : your static LAN IP_Address

protocol: ALL

**You can access to your web via ip:**
Your internet IP:80

for example my server: 27.72.173.170:80

**If you want to access via domain:**

Config your Xampp virtual host at (Your xampp directory)\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

And add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/yourwebdir"
ServerName yourdomain
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/yourwebdir">
Options Indexes
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to port forwarding using  your router panel (depends on your router specification).

Port-forward :

- 80 (apache/webserver)
- 3306 (mysql)

[image: example port forwading]

---

reference

- https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/